How to do cross-language LTO (link time optimization) on Windows using clang-cl and Rust?
I am using nightly rustc and LLVM 19.1 using clang-cl. I also unsuccessfully tried stable rustc 1.81.0 and clang-cl 18.1.8.
Versions
> rustc +nightly --version --verbose
rustc 1.83.0-nightly (9e394f551 2024-09-25)
binary: rustc
commit-hash: 9e394f551c050ff03c6fc57f190e0761cf0be6e8
commit-date: 2024-09-25
host: x86_64-pc-windows-msvc
release: 1.83.0-nightly
LLVM version: 19.1.0

> clang --version
clang version 19.1.0
Target: x86_64-pc-windows-msvc
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: C:\Program Files\LLVM\bin

Code compiled
minimal code to test that LTO works.
a.rs
#[no_mangle]
extern "C" fn add_2_numbers(arg: i32)->i32{
    arg + arg
}

b.c
#include <stdint.h>

int32_t add_2_numbers(int32_t arg);

[[clang::noinline]]
int32_t process_2_nums(int32_t x, int32_t y) {
  return add_2_numbers(x) * add_2_numbers(y);
}

main.c
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int32_t process_2_nums(int32_t x, int32_t y);

int32_t main() { 
    int32_t x = 0;
    int32_t y = 0;

    scanf("%d", &x);
    scanf("%d", &y);
    const int32_t value = process_2_nums(x, y);
    printf("Result is %d", value);
    return 0;
 }

I also tried a.c for checking if lto works if I only use c:
#include <stdint.h>

int32_t add_2_numbers(int32_t arg) { return arg + arg; }

I compile and link code like this:
rustc +nightly -Copt-level=3 -Ccodegen-units=1 -Clto=fat -Clinker-plugin-lto --crate-type=staticlib --emit=obj a.rs
clang-cl /clang:-std=c17 /clang:-O3 -c /D_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS=1 /clang:-flto=thin /clang:-fuse-ld=lld-link b.c
clang-cl /clang:-std=c17 /clang:-O3 -c /D_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS=1 /clang:-flto=thin /clang:-fuse-ld=lld-link main.c
lld-link /out:c_wrap_rust.exe a.o b.obj main.obj -verbose /threads:1

For some reason, function from Rust isn't inlined to function in C.
Disassembled code in Windows
sub_140001010 proc near
push    rsi
push    rdi
sub     rsp, 28h
mov     esi, edx
call    sub_140001000
mov     edi, eax
mov     ecx, esi
call    sub_140001000
imul    eax, edi
add     rsp, 28h
pop     rdi
pop     rsi
retn
sub_140001010 endp

; I would expect this function to be inlined.
sub_140001000 proc near
lea     eax, [rcx+rcx]
retn
sub_140001000 endp

I also tried to use -Clto=thin, compile rust code to static library and link with it, link code using clang-cl, all got to the same situation.
When I replace a.rs by a.c and link 3 object files from C, it works.
sub_140001000 proc near
imul    ecx, edx
lea     eax, ds:0[rcx*4]
retn
sub_140001000 endp

Linux
I also tried to do the same using Linux machine, everything works perfectly there:
Commands
clang-19 -std=c17 -O3 -c -flto=thin -o b.o b.c
clang-19 -std=c17 -O3 -c -flto=thin -o main.o main.c
rustc +nightly -Copt-level=3 -Ccodegen-units=1 -Clto=fat -Clinker-plugin-lto --crate-type=staticlib --emit=obj a.rs
clang-19 -flto -fuse-ld=lld a.o b.o main.o -o c_wrap_rust -v
llvm-objdump-19 --demangle --disassemble-symbols=process_2_nums c_wrap_rust

Result:
c_wrap_rust:    file format elf64-x86-64

Disassembly of section .text:

0000000000046820 <process_2_nums>:
   46820: 0f af fe                      imull   %esi, %edi
   46823: 8d 04 bd 00 00 00 00          leal    (,%rdi,4), %eax
   4682a: c3                            retq
   4682b: cc                            int3
   4682c: cc                            int3
   4682d: cc                            int3
   4682e: cc                            int3
   4682f: cc                            int3

Extra
I looked into output of lld-link with parameter /mllvm:-print-after-all, and it seems to me that it starts processing object files from C only after finishing emitting machine code for Rust (and it does optimize both C and Rust code during linking, but separately).
I also tried to pass /LTCG flag (MS link.exe lto flag) to the linker, didn't work.
How can I make cross-language link time optimization work on pc-windows-msvc?

I found a source of the problem: it is target features. When I added to -Ctarget-cpu=znver1 to rustc and /clang:-march=znver1 to clang, LLVM successfully inlined functions between languages.
As I understand, LLVM refuses inline functions from Rust because they require more CPU features compared to C.
So, final commands for successful LTO on Windows:
C: clang-cl /clang:-march=znver1 /clang:-std=c17 /clang:-O3 -c /D_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS=1 /clang:-flo=thin c_filename.c
For Rust: rustc -Copt-level=3 -Ctarget-cpu=znver1 -Ccodegen-units=1 -Clto=fat -Clinker-plugin-lto --crate-type=staticlib --emit=obj rust_filename.rs
And for linking: lld-link c_filename.obj rust_filename.o
